# Jquery, adding new function to the second click

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I am trying to add new effect after the first click. When submit is clicked for the first time it is working fine. How to make it function after the first click?

```
  if($('input#submit:not(.clicked)')){
                 $(this).addClass("clicked");
               $('.error').hide().fadeIn(700);
             }  else {
                 $('.error').fadeOut(10000).fadeIn(700);
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input#sumbit').click(function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass("clicked"))
  {
     $('.error').fadeOut(10000).fadeIn(700); // non-first click effect
  }
  else
  {
     $(this).addClass("clicked");
     $('.error').hide().fadeIn(700); //first click effect
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#submit').bind('click',function(){
    //your function here
    ...


    //and your new click function is here
    $('input#submit').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
        ...
    })
})
```