# Slightly change function on second click

Tags: jquery

I'm working on some sort of slot machine, and I have managed to set the outcome on a specific set of numbers. I want to achieve the same thing with a different set of endnumbers when I click the second time to spin the machine, but I don't understand the Jquery syntax well enough to realize this.

Here's a Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/ (note: code belongs to Matthew Lein)

Now here's the issue, the following piece of code works perfectly (in my HTML file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  

    $('.slot').jSlots({  
        spinner: '#playBtn',
        winnerNumber: 7,
        endNumbers: [1, 2, 3]
    }); 
</script>
```

I figured that I could use the answer to this question: [Jquery, adding new function to the second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723523/jquery-adding-new-function-to-the-second-click) leaving me with this bit of code:

```
$('.slot').click(function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass("clicked"))
  {
     $('.slot').jSlots({  
        spinner: '#playBtn',
        winnerNumber: 7,
        endNumbers: [3, 2, 1]; // non-first click effect
  }
  else
  {
     $(this).addClass("clicked");
     $('.slot').jSlots({  
        spinner: '#playBtn',
        winnerNumber: 7,
        endNumbers: [1, 2, 3]; //first click effect
  }
});
```

This of course renders my entire function unusable, and I'm pretty sure I'm just messing up on the syntax here. Please help me out. Thank you. I'm particularly confused with the use of the comma's and semicolon's at the end of some lines.

EDIT: typo

Comment: Give me a second, I will try to update your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle and modified the jQuery code a bit so it supports changing the options of an existing jsSlot.

The button now counts the clicks in the variable `clickCount`. Furthermore `$('.someSelector').jSlots()` now returns the jsSlots objects as an array.
So you can change the options on those objects at any time through this code:

```
var jsSlot = $('.slot').jSlots({
                spinner: '#playBtn',
                winnerNumber: 7,
                endNumbers: [1, 4, 3]
            })[0];

jsSlots.options.endNumbers = [5 , 2, 2];
```

You find your updated fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/435/

I also changed the endnumbers on the second click to `[1, 4, 6]` in the fiddle for a demo

Comment: Wow. This turned out to use a lot more code than I thought it would. Thank you very much for your example, works like a charm! Is there a way to easily update it if I want to show yet another combination on the third count?

Comment: Yes, just add `else if (clickCount == 3)
            {
                jsSlot.options.endNumbers = [1, 4, 1]; //<----- Different end numbers for thrid click
            }` to the code. See http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/438/

Comment: I just figured it out by myself, I was searching for the correct wording of 'else if'. Thank you so much though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slot').jSlots({  
    spinner: '#playBtn',
    winnerNumber: 7,
    endNumbers: [1, 2, 3];
```

should be

```
$('.slot').jSlots({  
    spinner: '#playBtn',
    winnerNumber: 7,
    endNumbers: [1, 2, 3] });
```

The argument should be of the `object` type, and you want to pass an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

Also, your code will trigger the `else` clause on every click but the first one, since you're adding the class on the second click, and then look for it on each click.

To count each click, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(){

    var prev = $(this).data('c');
    $(this).data({ c: !prev ? 1 : ++prev });

    var count = $(this).data('c');
    console.log(count);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7GHJ7/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It's not working for me though. I'm aware that the else clause will be triggered every time, that's currently not a problem. If it works for you, could you maybe change the jsfiddle and provivde your working example, thank you